# how to get an unique identifier to identify an appointment in outlook (appointment organizer mode)

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to find an unique identifier to identify a meeting scheduled using the outlook add-in (in Appointment Organizer).
I researched and found `GlobalAppointmentID`. An identifier for outlook meeting which doesn't change. but it could only be of use in VBA. I am trying to develop the add-in using javascript.
Is there any alternative to `GlobalAppointmentID`? I have already checked for `seriesId` but it doesn't fulfill the requirement. As `seriesId` is available only if I edit the meeting in series not for the original meeting invite as host.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From API set 1.8, the API [getItemIdAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.appointmentcompose?view=outlook-js-preview#getitemidasync-options--callback-) is available in Appointment Organizer and provides the item id, which can be used to identify the appointment.

Comment: I am getting "The id can't be retrieved until the item is saved."  I am trying to get the Item Id in the calendar event. The item is not getting saved till the time. won't the itemId change when I edit the meeting?

Comment: The item id is not available until the item is saved. You can save the item before calling getItemIdAsync but calling item.saveAsync first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.appointmentcompose?view=outlook-js-preview#saveasync-options--callback-

Comment: Also, please note that the itemId is not immutable. The itemId will change if the item is moved, for example, to a different folder. Currently, immutableIds are not supported. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. It looks like this feature has already been requested by others. Please upvote the existing request. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/39183742-get-immutable-id-s-from-office-js-context

Comment: ok, the Item id is changing even when I am trying to edit the same meeting. How do I check it's the same meeting which I am editing and I want to be able to identify the meetings which are being edited?

Comment: Could you explain your scenario to help us better understand the functionality you are looking for? With which client are you editing the meeting (OWA, win32, mac)? Are you editing a meeting that was sent?